# ActiveMQ 5.3.0 - Delete Inactive Destinations

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm running ActiveMQ 5.3.0 and I tried to follow the instructions here 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ACTIVEMQ/Delete+Inactive+Destinations
 to get my configuration to delete queues that have not had messages or 
consumers on them.

However, I updated my activemq.xml file and I'm getting this stack trace 
when I try to start activemq now.  Can anyone help?  I'm very new to 
activemq so I apologize if I'm doing something dumb.

```
ERROR: java.lang.Exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class 
path resource [activemq.xml]: Error setting property values; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid 
property 'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' of bean class 
[org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService]: Bean property 
'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' is not writable or has an invalid setter 
method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the 
getter? 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 | java.lang.Exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class 
path resource [activemq.xml]: Error setting property values; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid 
property 'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' of bean class 
[org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService]: Bean property 
'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' is not writable or has an invalid setter 
method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the 
getter? 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:99) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:129) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:79) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:251) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:107) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 | Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class 
path resource [activemq.xml]: Error setting property values; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid 
property 'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' of bean class 
[org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService]: Bean property 
'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' is not writable or has an invalid setter 
method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the 
getter? 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:96) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:52) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       at 
org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 |       ... 16 more 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/11/02 15:51:00 | Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 
'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' of bean class 
[org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService]: Bean property 
'schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge' is not writable or has an invalid setter 
method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the 
getter?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ActiveMQ version is to old for the configuration item you are trying to add.  Version 5.3.0 is quite old and you should really consider upgrading to a newer release with current fixes and security improvements.